# How can you open windows program by pressing a button on web page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How can you open windows program  by pressing a button on web page

I develop web app in asp.net, and I want to do some action in windows when press button on

the web page,

For example: when you press Messenger button in http://www.msn.com/?ocid=hmlogout

windows live messenger will open in your computer,

Is there a certain technique to do that ?

thanks for any suggestion.

Dani.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1. open applications associated with a protocol (as **citronas** said)
2. use a trusted applet/activex

Answer (score 2):

This will not work unless you try to upen a URI with an associated protocol on the client.

torrent:// or something like this.

Comment: +1. It can also work if the link points to a document that is associated with a local application, e.g. a link to a .doc file will usually open the document in Word. However, not all applications can be launched that way.

Comment: Thank you citronas, 
Your answer is make sense, but i still a little confuse about what is the best protocol and what are the classes in .net allocated for this purpose ?
thank y again.